# Crash on button click when I try to add items in ListView dynamically

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an `activity` named `EfortActivity` which contains 3 `EditText`, a `Spinner`, a `RadioGroup` and a `Button` - saveButton. My goal is to add data dynamically in a `ListView` (the `listView` is implemented in another `activity` called `HistoryActivity`).

The problem is that when I click on the `saveButton` my app crash.

Here is the code in `EfortActivity`:

```
public class EfortMonitorizareActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RadioGroup radioGroupDaNu;
Spinner spinnerTip;
EditText editTextDurata;
EditText editTextInainte;
EditText editTextDupa;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_efort_monitorizare);
    intent = getIntent();   
    initializareComponente();    
}

private void initializareComponente() {
    radioGroupDaNu = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg_activitateDANU);
    spinnerTip = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_tip_efort);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.TipEfort, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerTip.setAdapter(adapter);
    editTextDurata = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_durataAnt_efort);
    editTextInainte = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_greuteInainteAnt_efort);
    editTextDupa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_greutateDupaAnt_efort);

    Button btn_inregistrareDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_adaugaDate_efort);
    btn_inregistrareDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (validare()) {
                Efort efort = createPlayerFromComponents();
                if (efort != null) {
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.ADD_EFORT_KEY,efort);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private Efort createPlayerFromComponents() {

    RadioButton checkDaNu = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioGroupDaNu.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    String radioDaNu = checkDaNu.getText().toString();
    String tip = spinnerTip.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Integer durata = Integer.parseInt(editTextDurata.getText().toString());
    Integer inainte = Integer.parseInt(editTextInainte.getText().toString());
    Integer dupa = Integer.parseInt(editTextDupa.getText().toString());

    return new Efort(radioDaNu, tip, durata, inainte, dupa);
}

private boolean validare() {

    RadioButton nu = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button_nu_efort);

    if (editTextDurata.getText() == null || editTextDurata.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.addplayer_number_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    if (editTextInainte.getText() == null || editTextDurata.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.addplayer_number_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    if (editTextDupa.getText() == null || editTextDurata.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.addplayer_number_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }         }
```

Here is the code for `HistoryActivity`:

```
public class IstoricActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lvEfort;
List<String> listaEfort = new ArrayList<>();
Button deconectare;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_istoric);

    deconectare=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_deconectareIstoric);
    deconectare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    //initializare componente
    lvEfort = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lw_listaEfort);
    Efort efortDefault = new Efort("Da", "Tennis", 40, 55, 53);
    listaEfort.add(efortDefault.toString());

    //declarare + initializare adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaEfort);
    lvEfort.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And the class `Efort`:

```
public class Efort implements Parcelable {

private String radioDaNu;
private String tip;
private Integer durata;
private Integer inainte;
private Integer dupa;


public Efort(String radioDaNu, String tip, Integer durata, Integer inainte, Integer dupa) {        
    this.radioDaNu = radioDaNu;
    this.tip = tip;
    this.durata = durata;
    this.inainte = inainte;
    this.dupa = dupa;
}

public String getRadioDaNu() {
    return radioDaNu;
}

public void setRadioDaNu(String radioDaNu) {
    this.radioDaNu = radioDaNu;
}

public String getTip() {
    return tip;
}

public void setTip(String tip) {
    this.tip = tip;
}

public Integer getDurata() {
    return durata;
}

public void setDurata(Integer durata) {
    this.durata = durata;
}

public Integer getInainte() {
    return inainte;
}

public void setInainte(Integer inainte) {
    this.inainte = inainte;
}

public Integer getDupa() {
    return dupa;
}

public void setDupa(Integer dupa) {
    this.dupa = dupa;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Efort{" +
            // ", datePicker=" + datePicker +
            ", Activitate efort  :" + radioDaNu +
            ", tip : '" + tip + '\'' +
            ", tipm de : " + durata +
            ", inainte de antrenamnet aveam : " + inainte +
            ", dupa antrenamnet am : " + dupa +
            '}';
}

public Efort(Parcel in) {
    this.radioDaNu = in.readString();
    this.tip = in.readString();
    this.durata = in.readInt();
    this.inainte = in.readInt();
    this.dupa = in.readInt();
}

public static Parcelable.Creator<Efort> CREATOR = new Creator<Efort>() {
    @Override
    public Efort createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
        return new Efort(parcel);
    }

    @Override
    public Efort[] newArray(int i) {
        return new Efort[i];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(radioDaNu);
    parcel.writeString(tip);
    parcel.writeInt(durata);
    parcel.writeInt(inainte);
    parcel.writeInt(dupa);
}
}
```

Comment: can you attach stacktrace?

Comment: @ValentinBaryshev where i can find stacktrace?

Comment: logcat logs, Logcat tab in android studio

Comment: @ValentinBaryshev it is enormous :))

Comment: attach only "red" strings :)

Comment: @ValentinBaryshev yes yes, i selected only the errors and still is enormous. I'm trying to attach

Comment: @ValentinBaryshev i can't paste it. it too long. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159188/discussion-between-valentin-baryshev-and-mihaela-miki).

Answer (score 0):

When you called,

```
  finish()
```

it will stop your activity and finish it. Please remove that finish()